# How to login into the site using form data in Htmlunit

Tags: java, htmlunit

How to login to site which has the below form data, the submit does't have name or id

```
String URL="http://127.0.0.0/zero/login.jsp";
final HtmlPage resultPage = webclient.getPage(URL);

<form name="login" action="security_check" method='POST'>
                <input data-qa="login.username" type="text" class="text-box text-box--fluid" placeholder="Username" autofocus=true name='username'/>
                <input data-qa="login.password" type="password" class="text-box text-box--fluid" placeholder="Password" name='password'/>
                <button data-qa="login.submit" type="submit" class="btn btn--primary btn--large" onclick="submit_onclick(this)">Log In</button>
</form>
```

I have tried DefaultCredentialsProvider but it's not working

Answer (score 0):

You can try to access the submit button by its `xpath`:

```
HtmlButton button = page.getElementByXpath("//form[@name='login']/button").get(0);
page = (HtmlPage) button.click();
```